# nested queries and calculations all in the same query - is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

I am running a MySQL query to get all "users" with current orders.
(*It is possible for a user to have more than 1 associated orders in the db/query*).

However i also want to get the total order value for each user and total order count for each user that is being returned (within the below query).

I could do these calculations in PHP, but feel it is possible and would be neater all done within the same SQL query (if possible).

This is the basic query with no attempt to make the above calculations

```
SELECT u.UserID, u.UserName,
  o.OrdersID, o.OrderProductName, o.OrderProductQT, o.OrderTotalPrice, o.tUsers_UserID,     o.tOrderStatus_StatusID, o.OrderDate, o.OrderDateModified, o.OrderVoid, o.tProducts_ProductID,
 os.OrderStatusName,
  ud.UserDetailsName, ud.UserDetailsPostCode,
  p.ProductName, p.ProductImage1                    
FROM tusers u
  INNER JOIN torders o ON o.tUsers_UserID =  u.UserID   
  INNER JOIN torderstatus os ON os.OrderStatus_StatusID = o.tOrderStatus_StatusID
  INNER JOIN tuserdetails ud ON ud.tUsers_UserID = u.UserID
  LEFT JOIN tproducts p ON p.ProductID = o.tProducts_ProductID          
WHERE o.tOrderStatus_StatusID = ?
GROUP BY u.UserID
ORDER BY OrdersID DESC
```

I have tried various nested select queries, but none of them work (right)

Is what i want to do possible in SQL or should i just do it all in PHP once i have the returned query results?

Any advice is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried with COUNT(x) and SUM(x)?

Comment: yes, i have tried count() but the part i am struggling with is only to count() for each user

Comment: Can you use COUNT(x) in a SELECT inside the main SELECT?

Comment: that would count all results, and i only want to count where BY userID

Comment: i need something like "(count(o.OrderTotalPrice)) ON o.tUsers_UserID = u.UserID as OrderPriceCount" but this obviously does not work.... :-(

Comment: SELECT u.UserID, ...., p.ProductImage1, (SELECT COUNT(o.OrdersID) WHERE torders.tUsers_UserID = tusers.UserID) ...

Comment: try something like

select UserID, count(*) as xcount from <your joins> group by UserID

and

select UserID, sum(OrderTotalPrice) as xsum from <your joins> group by UserID

as separate Views to probably join them over UserID to your main-select to give you two more columns...

Answer (score 1):

You can embed the slightly modified queries into another query. For instance:

```
SELECT userid, SUM(orderid) FROM orders GROUP BY userid
```

and

```
SELECT userid, SUM(distinct productid)
FROM
  orders o
  INNER JOIN orderlines ol on ol.orderid = o.orderid
GROUP BY
  userid
```

can be combined to:

```
SELECT
  u.userid
  u.fullname,

  (SELECT SUM(orderid) 
   FROM orders o
   WHERE o.userid = u.userid) as ORDERCOUNT,

  (SELECT SUM(distinct productid)
  FROM
    orders o
    INNER JOIN orderlines ol on ol.orderid = o.orderid
  WHERE
    o.userid = u.userid) as UNIQUEPRODUCTS
FROM
  users u
```

Note that the latter query will return all users and will return `NULL` for ORDERCOUNT or UNIQUEPRODUCTS when the subquery doesn't return anything (when a user doesn't have orders). Also, the query will fail when a subquery returns more than 1 row, which should never happen in the example I posted.